# Calling method with same name for different types

Tags: c#

I'm working with an old (.NET 1) API I cannot change. The API has no interfaces. I have a base class (`Pet`) with concrete classes (`Cat`, `Parrot`) that have essentially the 'same' method (`GetLegs()`). I want my helper class to 'abtract away' and just call the method using the type of the instance. I want to avoid reflection.

My attempt has my switching on type. Is this a reasonable approach? SHould I be concerned (on a 'theory' level) that `Type` is too general?

```
namespace TheApi
{
    public class Pet
    {
    }

    public class Cat : Pet
    {
        public string[] GetLegs() =>
            new[] { "Front left", "Front right", "Back left", "Back right" };
    }

    public class Parrot : Pet
    {
        public string[] GetLegs() =>
            new[] { "Left", "Right" };
    }
}

namespace MyApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using TheApi;
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static string[] GetLegsFor(Pet pet)
        {
            return MapTypeToGetter[pet.GetType()](pet);
        }

        private static Dictionary<Type, Func<Pet, string[]>> MapTypeToGetter =>
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<Pet, string[]>>
            {
                [typeof(Cat)] = p => ((Cat)p).GetLegs(),
                [typeof(Parrot)] = p => ((Parrot)p).GetLegs()
            };
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Pet bird = new Parrot();
            var legs = Helper.GetLegsFor(bird);

            var expectedLegs = new[] { "Left", "Right" };
            Assert.That(legs, Is.EqualTo(expectedLegs));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have  an interface - `IHaveLegs`.

Comment: Why not simply use an extension method on `Pet`?

Comment: @DanielA.White The OP said: I'm working with an old (.NET 1) API I cannot change. The API has no interfaces.

Comment: Are `Cat` and `Parrot` implemented from you?

Comment: In what way does the API impose any constraints on the rest of your code?

Comment: You are essentially trying to implement manual Polymorphism. Why in the world would you want to do that when the language supports it natively?

Comment: You have a big opportunity to send an instance where the type is not in the dictionary. Hence failing at run time.

Comment: you could subclass each of the pets that have legs then decorate them with the interfaces that way.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I can't subclass (because factory, no public constructors) but I can wrap each type in my own type with appropriate interface. But do you mean something specific by 'decorate' i.e. decorator pattern?

Answer (score 2):

> I want my helper class to 'abtract away' and just call the method using the type of the instance. I want to avoid reflection.

I would not write a helper class at all. I'd write an extension method:

```
namespace PetesExtensions 
{
  public static class PetExtensions 
  {
    public static string[] GetLegs(this Pet pet)
    {
      if (pet == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("pet");
      if (pet is Cat) return ((Cat)pet).GetLegs();
      if (pet is Parrot) return ((Parrot)pet).GetLegs();
      throw new Exception(
        $"I don't know how to get the legs of a {pet.GetType().Name}. Contact Pete Moloy.");
    } 
  }
}
```

And then you can say

```
using PetesExtensions;
...
Pet p = whatever;
string[] legs = p.GetLegs();
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm trying to chew on OOP concept.  What would be the advantage of creating an extension method v. an interface.  Suppose I want to create a a `Worm` class which can be a `pet` but has no legs.  Wouldn't I be better off using an interface so I can choose which pet gets legs or not?  Thanks.

Comment: @Zuzlx: Of course that would be better. The premise of the question is that using an interface is not possible. Re-read the first two sentences of the question.

Comment: Extension method is syntactic sugar, which I can add to mine. But does your appraoch really differ from mine i.e. we both switch on type, no?